# Using Self as generic parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have simple generic class:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    let closure: (T -> Void)

    init(closure: T -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
}
```

I would like to write an extension for `UIView` which would apply closure to any subclass of `UIView`:

```
extension UIView {
    func apply(c: MyClass<Self>) -> Self {
        c.closure(self)
        return self
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error: `'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class`.

Is there any solution to fix this code?

Comment: Just use `UIView` instead of `Self`?

Comment: @kennytm I've already tried it. If I use `UIView` instead of `Self`, I won't be able to invoke this method on subclass of `UIView`, like `UILabel` because `MyClass<UILabel>` is not a subclass of `MyClass<UIView>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a protocol that UIView and in turn all subclasses will adopt:

```
protocol View {}
extension UIView:View {}

extension View  {
    func apply(c:MyClass<Self>) -> Self {
        c.closure(self)
        return self
    }
}

let m = MyClass<UILabel>(closure: {t in})
let l = UILabel().apply(m) // UILabel returned
```