# UIView extension weird behavior when using generics

Tags: swift

When extending UIView with a generic closure parameter it doesn't properly access the generic variable.

```
extension UIView {
    public func apply(_ s : (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        s(self)
        return self
    }
}

let b = UIButton().apply { $0.setTitle("Button", for: .normal) }
```

Above code produces an error

> Value of type 'Self' has no member 'setTitle'

However the return type is indeed a UIButton.

Comment: change the extension from `UIViiew` to `UIButton` or downcast `$0 as! UIButton` .

Comment: I'm welling to keep it generic, it works as return value but not in closure as stated above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a generic apply() function in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830927/how-to-write-a-generic-apply-function-in-swift). – See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966149/1187415.

Comment: Thank you, that made the trick! Any reason why it doesn't work by default?

Comment: A related discussion in the Swift forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/generic-method-in-class-extension/21359.

Comment: Thanks for the update, apparently Self usage can be ambiguous to the compiler at certain cases and hopefully will be resolved by an upcoming update.